# postgres how to insert values with 2 selects

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I'm trying to do a query on Postgres but it's not working. I'd like to create an insert query with 2 select:

Example :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id_1, id_2)
SELECT id from table_2 where code='01',
SELECT id from table_2 where code='02';
```

I don't find the good syntax for this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe below query will works for your use case

```
INSERT INTO stats(totalProduct, totalCustomer, totalOrder)
VALUES(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders)
);
```

you can changes query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more `SELECT` to achieve this

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (id_1, id_2)
SELECT 
    (SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE code = '01') AS Id_1,
    (SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE code = '02') AS Id_2;
```

Or you may try with [CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/functions-conditional.html):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id_1, id_2)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN code = '01' THEN id ELSE 0 END) AS Id_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN code = '02' THEN id ELSE 0 END) AS Id_2
FROM table_2
```

Please refer to the [working fiddle on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2caef3d666962477c15c9a22037e2284)